# Visual Studio 2008 and Visual C# 2008 Express compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, compatibility, c#

I'm sure this must have been answered somewhere, but I can't find it for the moment...

Suppose I have Visual Studio 2008 Pro at work and Visual C# 2008 Express at home.

Can I use these interchangeably with a solution?

(I am aware of the limitations of the Express version, e.g. no add-ins, no built-in setup project, single language projects, etc. Assume any solution I have in mind contains only C# projects.)

i.e.

- Work on app at home, commit to SVN.
- Checkout app at work, change, recompile, commit to SVN.
- Checkout at home, carry on working.
- rinse, repeat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are not hitting those limitations, you are fine.
I use them interchangeably all the time.